# Deleting via autofilter takes too long

Tags: excel, vba

I have roughly 8000+ rows. Using autofilter to delete rows takes a few minutes. I thought autofilter was the defacto FAST way to delete (instead of looping row by row). How can I speed it up? Is there a faster way? To be fair, half of the rows are deleted XD

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 19))
    dataRng.AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:="=0"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dataRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dataRng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .ShowAllData
End With
```

Comment: Can the data be sorted?  If so you could add a column with a formula `=$S1=0` or something of that sort, copied down, and then sort first, deleting the first occurrence (if it exists) to the last row?

Comment: Or sometimes what I do is filter the "good" data, copy it into a new sheet, and then copy the new sheet back into the old.

Comment: Hmm sort might work...

Comment: try to check what takes the most time... im sure it will be the deleting itself... sorting may do the trick like Demetri said... deleting every second row for 4k rows will be much slower than deleting row 1:10000... test it

Comment: After I sort, what's the quickest way to determine first row that's not 0? A loop? or a find? or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll challange to underlying assumption that AutoFilter is the fast way to go - it is often hard to beat a loop over a variant array

This demo shows a way to do this, on my system processing 8000+ rows removing half runs in sub-second

```
Sub DEMO()
    Dim datrng As Range
    Dim dat, newdat
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload")
        Set datrng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp))
    End With
    dat = datrng.Value
    ReDim newdat(1 To UBound(dat, 1), 1 To UBound(dat, 2))
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 19) <> 0 Then ' test for items you want to keep
            For k = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
                newdat(j, k) = dat(i, k)
            Next
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    datrng = newdat
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, my range starts in cells(4,1) but will read through this while I test^^

Answer (score 4):

I tested the macros for speed and found that sorting, autofiltering and deleting is faster then building an array.

Using the timing code [here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time) I run the original code over 100k lines of random data (25 columns wide random numbers between 0-4).

-Original code took 78 seconds (only ran 50k rows here to speed it up)

-The array code presented by chris took 1.91 seconds

-The code below took 0.84 seconds (Tried running it sorting ascending and descending and it made little difference if the range of zeros was sorted to the top or the bottom.

I realize the built in clock isn't great in vba but the difference is enough that I am comfortable saying sorting,filtering, deleting is at least as fast as arrays in this case.

The code below just added `dataRng.Sort key1:=Range("S4"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes` to the original code

```
Sub test()

With Sheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 25))
    dataRng.Sort key1:=Range("S4"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    dataRng.AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:="=0"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dataRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dataRng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .ShowAllData
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Huh. So sorting it first makes it faster.