# Are array formulas an acceptable alternative to loops?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using VBA for a while now and began thinking that often times I'm too quick to use a loop.  They seem to be inefficient and cumbersome sometimes.  However, I haven't come across too many alternatives when browsing other real life examples, so I'm wondering if anyone tries using array formulas instead and if there are any disadvantages I'm not considering.

Obviously I know that this alternative will not be able to replace most loops, but for a lot of simple worksheet loops it might.  I made this sub to easily demonstrate how an array formula is 13 seconds faster than a loop when it comes to displaying month names for only 500 rows.

```
Sub speedtest()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim time2 As Date
Set sht = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With sht
    .Range("A1").Value = "Dates"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Array Formula"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Loop"
    .Range("F1").Value = "Formula Time - seconds"
    .Range("G1").Value = "Loop Time - seconds"
    .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    .Range("A2:A500").Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(41817, 42395)"
    .Range("A2:A500").Value = .Range("A2:A500").Value
    'Array formula
    time2 = Now
    .Range("B2:B500").FormulaArray = "=TEXT(A2:A500," & Chr(34) & "mmmm" & Chr(34) & ")"
    .Range("B2:B500").Value = .Range("B2:B500").Value
    .Range("F2").Value = (Now - time2) * 24 * 60 * 60
    'Loop
    time2 = Now
    For x = 2 To 500
        .Range("C" & x).Value = Format(.Range("A" & x).Value, "mmmm")
    Next x
    .Range("G2").Value = (Now - time2) * 24 * 60 * 60
    .Columns("A:G").AutoFit
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028430/deleting-via-autofilter-takes-too-long).

Comment: Well if you create ListObject lists in sheets, you have a very easy time keeping formatting and formulas consistent for all rows. Using this, I can handle sheets with hundreds of thousands of rows, inserting and deleting at will, without caring about the many formulas in that (or other) sheets. So I do not see any reason for creating VBA loops just to create formulas.

Comment: @findwindow That is cool.  Didn't he forget to clear the old data before putting in the new values though?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The arrays are empty to begin with. There's no old data.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that the newdat array was dimensioned to be the same size as the original range, so I thought when the newdat array values were put on the old range, the newdat array would be smaller and the old range would overlap.  I see what it's doing now.  That is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

I'd almost always plump for using arrays:

1) They will be faster.

2) They tend to reduce the amount of VBA. No bad thing: VBA is considered to be a security hazard; many institutions disallow `xlsm` workbooks.

3) It's difficult to overtype an array formula by accident. This helps to make a spreadsheet less brittle.

One exception: I do find single cell array formulas pernicious: it's too easy to "un-array" them following an edit.