# How can I improve performance in an Excel VBA For loop with nested If loop?

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops, ranged-loops

This is my first post, so if I need to make any changes, please let me know.

I've found a few examples of ways to optimize loops, but I cannot seem to apply any of them effectively to my code.  What I'm trying to do is loop through about 170 cells in a single column, and hide or show the entire row based on whether the cell value is 0 or not.

I want the code to run each time I activate certain sheets.  Right now this piece of code is taking about 4 seconds to run.  It seems like it should be much faster than that! That's why I'm here for help.

Here is the code I'm using (FormatSheet returns a BOOLEAN where True means that it is okay to perform this code on this sheet and False means to skip performing this code on this sheet:

```
Private Sub mobjWb_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim r As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim varray As Variant

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

If Not FormatSheet(Sh) Then
Exit Sub
End If

Set varray = Range("$F$1", Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(x1up)).Value


For Each r In varray

z = r.Value
If z = 0 Then
Range("F" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Range("F" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next r


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried autofilter?

Comment: This line `Set varray = Range("$F$1", Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(x1up)).Value` has a typo.  There is a `1` instead of an `l` in `xlup`. If this is not just a transfer typo I would bet that you are cycling through all 1 million + rows.

Comment: @ScottCraner - good catch. Another good reason to always use `Option Explicit` ...

Comment: Does this compile? I don't think you can 'For Each' with a Long variable. Also, why do you assign the range to a variant? The range itself is a very usable array. Lastly, I think the 'Find' function is usually faster then looping a range.

Comment: @ScottCraner That actually is a "one" in that line.  It must look different when copied.  Also, I did use Option Explicit--it was just further up in the code in this Class Module.  Thanks!

Comment: @findwindow No, I have not tried autofilter, and unfortunately I'm not sure how to do that.  I can google it like I have just about everything in my code, though, unless you happen to have an easy example that would work.  Thanks!

Comment: I was [deleting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028430/deleting-via-autofilter-takes-too-long), not hiding but should be same idea. The answer posted there is pretty amazing but not sure if applicable to you.

Comment: It should not be a 'one' it should be an lowercase 'L' as in `XLUP` not `X1UP`

Answer (score 0):

With several very slight changes:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim z As Long, N As Long
   Dim varray As Range

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
   Set varray = Range("F1:F" & N)

   For Each r In varray
      z = r.Value
      If z = 0 Then
         r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Else
         r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End If
   Next r

   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

run quite rapidly

Comment: I'm trying this now.  Is this part still ok (before the For Each statement)?
`code` 
If Not FormatSheet(Sh) Then
Exit Sub
End If
`code`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may speed up it a little bit.. I would not use **z** variable. You can do the same with existing **r**.

```
For Each r In varray
If r.Value = 0 Then
    Range("F" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Range("F" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest way could be to use autofilter. Set the autofilter with values <> 0 and voilà!