# Code to remove 'NULL' values

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Let me give a quick layout what our process is:

I export a report into Excel (Let's call this workbook "Raw Data"). I run an Extract macro on the imported file:

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1601_January()
'
Dim ANS As Long

ANS = MsgBox("Is the January 2016 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
If ANS = vbNo Or IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - January 2016") = False Then
    MsgBox "The required workbook is not currently open. Please open the correct file and restart the Extract process. This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
    Exit Sub
End If

    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "1" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:Z2000")
    .Apply
End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, this will copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, this will paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This copies data from the "extract" file into another workbook (This workbook is called "Swivel"). This part completes successfully. Once this is completed, in the "Swivel" workbook, we then run a remove duplicates macro:

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Somewhere between the copying of data into the 'Swivel' workbook and running the Remove Duplicates macro, there is a null value (I think) inserted into the cells in column AD in the rows just pasted in. I only know this because this code is running in the worksheet for changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

    If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Don’t change header color

    If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then 
        r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
        r.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

For clarification, here is where the above subs reside:

**Extract_Sort_1601_January** is part of an Add-in I created for the "raw data" file.

**Remove_Duplicates** is in a module in the "Swivel" workbook.

**WorkSheet_Change** is in the Sheet1 object in the "Swivel" workbook.

1. Data from the reporting site is exported to the "raw data" workbook
2. Extract_Sort_1601_January copies data into the existing "Swivel"
   workbook (In this case that workbook name is "Swivel - Master -
   January 2016.xlsm")
3. Remove_Duplicates is initiated on the "Swivel" workbook.

If there is no data in column AD of the "Swivel" workbook, the text in that row should be black. However, that is not the case after running the Remove Duplicates macro, the text is green. If I go to the 'empty' cell (column AD) in that row and click delete, then the row changes to black text. I also checked to see if there is a space in the cell, but there is not. How do I code the removal of this 'null' value that is making the Worksheet Change sub believe there is a value in the cell? And, can this be added to the 'Remove Duplicates' sub?

Thanks for all the assistance!

Comment: `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Copy | .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial` you're only copy/pasting columns A to Z. How does AD come into play? Also, perhaps you might want to consider conditional formatting instead of `worksheet_change` event.

Comment: That is part of this mystery. I have nothing that is affecting or altering the cells in column AD, but somehow they are. And Conditional Formatting does not work. When we have multiple records using the same incident number, we only need to use one date. So, the users are copying and pasting the date into the next 3 rows down. This messes up the ranges in the CF rule (even absolute referencing). So this bit of code has proved invaluable.

Comment: As much as I want it to be true, computers are not sentient (yet) so someone is altering column AD or you have other code or I am missing something. Try deleting AD and start fresh? I don't know :/

Comment: @findwindow Well, I would believe that someone could possibly alter the cells in column AD. But....I created this new today and did all the testing myself. I thought I might be missing something as well, that is why I am posting here. I just don't see how those cells are all of a sudden containing some sort of invisible value. Thanks for trying though findwindow. All your assistance in the past has been very helpful.

Comment: With all that said, we may not find where this phantom value is coming from. But my question is: How do I code the removal of this 'null' value that is making the Worksheet Change sub believe there is a value in the cell? And, can this be added to the 'Remove Duplicates' sub?

Comment: Null values are a pain so easiest (for me) to just delete column. Worksheet Change is a built in event. You can't add it to your own sub. Edit: hmmm my code may be bad. Hold on.

Comment: Add `x = Target.Row` and change previous line to`If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, "AD").Value <> "" Then` Edit: You placed the worksheet change code in the sheet module in question yes? Not in a separate module.

Comment: Yes, it is in the worksheet object.

Comment: @findwindow Should I "Add" or replace that bit of code from your comment?

Comment: is column "AD" contain formulas?

Comment: Add the first line. Replace the second. I don't think it actually makes a difference XD

Comment: @Fadi No. There are no formulas anywhere in the workbook.

Comment: @findwindow Sorry to report that did not work. it did not cause any errors, but it did not correct the issue.

Comment: So I have run another test. Rows 12 through 22 are blank. I added zero's into AD12:AD22. All turned to green text as per the Worksheet_Change sub. Then I ran the Extract code that copies and pastes the data into the Swivel workbook. Once this completed I find it strange that A12:AD22 is now all black text. The zero's are still in the cells I placed earlier. So, something in that copy and paste sub is where the culprit is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wait. Which book is the code residing in? The worksheet change code needs to be in destination book, not source. In other words, you need to copy paste Swivel into destination book (where code is). Edit: should've mentioned this earlier... should qualify your ranges.

Comment: @findwindow Good questions. I edited my original question to address your questions and hope that helps clarify.

Comment: I would qualify your ranges (really everything) in your extract sub. `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Copy` can refer to anything even if it looks like it's working. Other than that, I am out of ideas :/ Going home. Edit: also, do you really need formatting? If not, set ranges to each other... someone wrote code for me that works amazingly well. Will dig up tomorrow.

Comment: @findwindow Thanks. I appreciate all the effort Going home too. :)

Comment: @findwindow I figured out the issue. It was not anything with the code (per se). See my answer. Thank you for all the help and effort you put into this.

Comment: @findwindow found the answer.

Comment: @Fadi Figured it out. Thank you and findwindow for all the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test this code:

```
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long
dim i as long
LastRow = 100 'change this to the last row (if it work)
Application.EnableEvents = True

 For i = 2 To LastRow
  If Trim(Range("AD" & i).Value) = "" Then Range("AD" & i).ClearContents
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Fadi Variable 'i' is not defined

Comment: @IronMan, ok i change it, try it again

Comment: This did not work either. This is a tough one. So, how do I run the Remove Duplicates code and then immediately check the cells in column AD where there is data in the row from columns A through Z only, and delete the 'invisible' contents in AD?

Comment: @IronMan, sorry,if this did not work , I don't know other way to check if the cells contain invisible data.

Comment: No apologies. Thanks for trying. I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @IronMan, I hope someone can help us to know what is the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. Please see answer above. Even though this is not a VBA code issue, I feel that this question and answer still bring value to this site as sometimes you need to look beyond the code when there is an issue, even when it looks as though it is the code that appears to be the problem.

Comment: I used the code you provided as a call in the Remove_Duplicates sub. This has done the trick and works instantly.

Comment: @IronMan, thank you, I have similar problem and really want to know what is the reason of this problem, but i'm not using filter at all, maybe someday I will add a new question, but now I can't do that because my code is very long.

Answer (score 2):

We extract the file from an internal site. It was brought to my attention that the reporting team had changed their preferences in their instance of the reporting tool to export files using Excel XP/2003 version settings. All the code I have compiled was using the same report, but in 2007 and newer formatting. Once this change in preferences was changed for the reporting team to use 2007 and newer for the exports, this issue was corrected. So in the end, the code was fine and there was no ghost. This proves that communication and Change Management are excellent tools. Thanks to everyone who tried to help figure this one out. All your effort is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cool. As previously mentioned, instead of copy paste, you may consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028430/deleting-via-autofilter-takes-too-long). That answer deserves far more upvotes than it has.

Comment: @findwindow I will try that, thanks. And I gave it an upvote (hint...hint) XD.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there are lots of "fake empty" cells in the worksheet. I have not been able to figure out where these came from, but I found this code and integrated it into the Remove_Duplicates sub to **ClearContents**:

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim usedrng As Range

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$2000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes

    For Each usedrng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If usedrng.Value = "" Then
            usedrng.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So now, this code works as intended:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

    If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Don’t change header color

    If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then 
        r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
        r.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks to everyone who helped get me to this point.

Comment: that is good, but make sure there is no formulas that return empty string in your used range, because this way will delete them.

Comment: @Fadi There are no formula's in these workbooks, but I will keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry I asked you this before and you tell me there is no formula in the workbook, I just forget that.