# VBA Excel Assigning Worksheets to Variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a "Run-time Error '13' Type Mismatch" when attempting to assign a worksheet to a variable. It works for all of the other worksheets but is seems to only happen to this worksheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub TS()
Dim RD, Dep, QC, MM, Pro As Workbook

With ThisWorkbook
Set RD = .Sheets("RawData")
Set Dep = .Sheets("Departments")
Set QC = .Sheets("QC")
Set MM = .Sheets("MM")
Set Pro = .Sheets("Production") 'I have a problem with this line
End With

End Sub
```

My worksheet labels are below:

[image]

Comment: You declared them as `workbook/variant`...

Comment: Actually you only set Pro as workbook, which should be worksheet.  All the others are declared as variant.  You need to declare them `Dim RD as WorkSheet, Dep as Worksheet, QC as Worksheet, MM as Worksheet, Pro As WorkSheet`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is pertinent to your erroneous declaration:

```
Pro As Workbook
```

You should declare it as `Worksheet`, or just `variant` without specifying the type, like:

```
Dim RD, Dep, QC, MM, Pro
```

A better way would be  to use the strong typed declaration:

```
Dim RD As Worksheet, Dep As Worksheet, QC As Worksheet, MM As Worksheet, Pro As Worksheet
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: ...pertinent to your erroneous declaration...  Pure gold.  +1

Comment: Why is it that the simplest answers always gets the most upvotes XD [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028430/deleting-via-autofilter-takes-too-long) is far more deserving of upvotes for instance.

Answer (score 3):

What your code should look like:

```
Sub TS()
  Dim RD as Worksheet
  Dim Dep as Worksheet
  Dim QC as Worksheet
  Dim MM as Worksheet
  Dim Pro as Worksheet

  With This.Workbook
    Set RD = .Sheets("RawData")
    Set Dep = .Sheets("Departments")
    Set QC = .Sheets("QC")
    Set MM = .Sheets("MM")
    Set Pro = .Sheets("Production") 
  End With
End Sub
```

You are setting a bunch of worksheets, so they need to be assigned to `Worksheet` variables.
The only reason your code didn't crash on `Set RD = ...` is that all your variables except `Pro` were declared as `Variant`.