# Naming Dynamic Range and turning it into a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to name a range based on a .Find then define that range as my variable so I can enter the variable into a different function. When I run the code I get a type mismatch error.

```
Sub Faked()
Dim r As Range
Cells.Find(What:="EE status", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Name = "Win"
Set r = ("Win")


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Set r = range("Win")`

Comment: @findwindow Dude I wish you would answer some of these.  we need to get you above 2000 so you can edit the questions.

Comment: Brilliant. That got rid of my error message. When I mouse over the r to see if the code picked it up it isn't showing the name or anything. Is there a different way to check to see if it is working besides using the variable?

Comment: `for each c in r | debug.print c | next`?

Comment: You could `Debug.Print r.Address` it will show you the range address in the immediate window.

Comment: @ScottCraner it's not really deserving of points/more of a comment.

Comment: @findwindow I disagree, It corrected the problem.  So defacto it was the correct answer and would close this question off the unanswered list.

Comment: @ScottCraner well, this has been answered a million times before. Besides, I am just here to troll.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you both very much. @Findwindow I have found out that if you are online my questions get answered much more clearly and quickly than any other time..

Comment: @TonyP lol I am pretty sure you mean Scott.

Comment: Tony - please come back in ten minutes and mark @findwindow answer as correct, so this can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @findwindow Actually you are the only one to ever answer my questions. This is the first time I have seen Scott.

Comment: @TonyP !!!!!! well, you're missing out. Scott's far far better than I.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am planning on it. If my questions get answered I never leave them unanswered.  Would either of you be willing to help me with the next step in my code? I need to figure out how to put the variables I just created in my other code.

Comment: @findwindow that depends on what you are asking.  I personally am doing as little as possible right now.

Comment: @TonyP please ask a new question.

Comment: Am I doing what? @findwindow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Scott says so. Try `Set r = range("Win")`

To test if `r` picked up the range correctly, one could do

```
for each c in r
    debug.print c
next
```

Edit: or if you're cool like Dirk,

```
Set r = [Win]
```

Comment: lol This is so not worth 4 upvotes. I mean, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028430/deleting-via-autofilter-takes-too-long) only got the same number of votes and is much much more impressive. Edit: also, whoever did that left me a comment but deleted it before I can catch it...

Comment: LOL  do you want me to downvote it?   I won't do it unless you're OK with that...

Comment: @UnEscapedCharacter I am ok with that.

Comment: @DirkReichel are you doing that?

Comment: @findwindow just tried that but I guess I am still too new on SO but thanks for your support, feel free to return the favor anytime, LOL

Comment: @UnEscapedCharacter oh. So you can upvote but not down... come back when you can^^

Answer (score 5):

Replace the code with this:

```
    Dim r As Range
Cells.Find(What:="EE status", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Set r = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
r.Name = "Win"
```

**Explanation:**

You cannot use the SET command with the name property of the range object.  The object needs to be populated with the range selection first, then you can just use the property of the object to assign a value to it, in this case the Name property of it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad to help, just don't forget to keep track of all the object variables in the code... give them a name that is easy to understand, like "rngMyEmployeeStatus" and so on...!  ;)